# Store pair values in vector C++ from a 2d vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, std-pair

I've been given a 2D vector (A). I need to store values of row and column index of that vector which contains element 0.

Here is my code-

```
vector<pair<int,int>>v;
   for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++){
       for(int j=0;j<A[i].size();j++){
           if(A[i][j]==0){
               v.push_back(make_pair(i.first,j.second));
           }
       }
   }
```

But I've been getting this error

> error: '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traitsstd::allocator<std::vector<int >,
> std::vector >::value_type' {aka 'class std::vector'} has no
> member named 'first'
>
> error: '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traitsstd::allocator<std::vector<int >,
> std::vector >::value_type' {aka 'class std::vector'} has no
> member named 'second'

Comment: You edited the code, but not the error message. Are you sure you're still getting the same error?

Comment: `i` and `j` are your `int` indecies...

Comment: Solved the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`int`s do not have members named `first` or `second`.

To add to the vector of pairs representing 2D indices, you simply need:

```
if(A[i][j]==0) {
    v.push_back({i, j});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While making pairs you just need to input the values into make_pair function.
If you want to make a pair out of (i, j) values then you write `make_pair(i,j)`. To access the values you use the `first` and `second` members.

```
if(A[i][j] == 0){
   v.push_back(make_pair(i,j));
}
```

And to access these values you write `v[i].first` and `v[i].second`.

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work

```
vector<pair<int,int>>v;
for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++){
   for(int j=0;j<A[i].size();j++){
       if(A[i][j]==0){
           v.push_back(make_pair(i,j));
       }
   }
}
```